# Is there a way to pass a class instance to dunder init?

Tags: python

A "task" class instance needs to contain information about its prerequisite tasks.

```
import typing

class Task:
    def __init__(
        self, 
        prerequisite: typing.Set(Task)
    ):
        self.prerequisite = prerequisite
```

```
File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Task:
  File "test.py", line 6, in Task
    prerequisite: typing.Set(Task)
NameError: name 'Task' is not defined
```

Comment: The question needs more context, what is this code, what are you trying to do, where do you need help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use and Abstract Class

```py
from abc import ABC
import typing

class TaskType(ABC):
    pass

class Task:
    def __init__(self, prerequisite: typing.Set(TaskType)):
        self.prerequisite = prerequisite
```

Comment: Obligatory quote: "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection... except for the problem of too many layers of indirection."